# Why are there here at most $ \vartriangle \cdot E $ paths?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I ran across this proof from the following paper: [Finding and Counting Given Length Cycles](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Evirgi/cs267/papers/cycles-ayz.pdf)

But I do not understand the third line.

> There are at most $ \vartriangle \cdot E $ such paths and they can be found in $O(\vartriangle \cdot E)$ time.

Why is that?

[image]

Comment: They consider paths of length 2, where the intermediate vertex has degree $\le \Delta$. In such path $u \to v \to w$, $u \to v$ can be any edge (giving factor $E$ in $O(E \Delta)$) and $v \to w$ can be any edge from $v$; since degree of $v$ is at most $\Delta$, it gives factor $\Delta$ in $O(E \Delta)$.

Comment: Got it to thank you so much! Do you know why it takes only $O(E\Delta )$ to find the paths? And also in line 5 "If no triangle is found this way, then it must be composed of three high degree vertices". Why couldn't it be any path of length 2 with a middle high-degree vertice?

Answer (score 2):

There are at most $E \cdot \Delta$ paths whose middle vertex has low degree. Indeed, any such path is composed of an edge $x\to y$, where $y$ has degree at most $\Delta$, and an edge $y \to z$. There are at most $E$ choices for $x\to y$, and since $y$ has degree at most $\Delta$, at most $\Delta$ choices for $y\to z$. This also shows how to find all these paths in time $O(E\cdot\Delta)$: just go over all directed edges $x\to y$, and whenever $y$ has low degree, go over all edges $y\to z$.

If a triangle $abc$ is not found this way, this means that there is no way to arrange its vertices so that the middle vertex has low degree. Some possible orderings are $abc,bca,cab$, showing that if *any* of the three vertices has low degree, then it is possible to arrange its vertices so that the middle vertex has low degree. Hence if $abc$ is not found in this way, all of its vertices must have high degree.